# Error when I want to deploy SSIS package in vs 2017

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, visual-studio-2017, package

When I want to deploy the SSIS package in vs 2017 and I got this message.
Can someone guide me on how to resolve this issue?

[image: this error occurred]
Thanks

### TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services

An error occurred during decryption. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15466)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=15.00.2000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15466&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

---

I tried this query in Microsoft SQL Server 2019 :

```
USE [SSISDB];
GO
ALTER MASTER KEY force REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';

OPEN MASTER KEY 
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';
ALTER MASTER KEY
DROP ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
ALTER MASTER KEY 
ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem :

first I renamed the SSIDB database to SSIDB2 as below script :

```
USE SSISDB
GO
ALTER DATABASE SSISDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE SSISDB MODIFY NAME = SSISDB2
GO
ALTER DATABASE SSISDB2 SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

and after that, I created a new SSIDB database as following link that describes how to create the SSIS Catalog database (SSISDB)

https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-to-the-ssis-catalog-database-ssisdb/

then I deployed the package in VS 2017 successfully.